# Multiple types of contacts

Tags: c#

I have a list of contacts, classified into categories. Each category is represented with a different class.

Base class:

```
class Contact
{
    public ushort Id { get; private set; }
    public Phone Phone { get; private set; }

    public Contact(ushort id, Phone phone)
    {
        Id = id;
        Phone = phone;
    }
}
```

And here are the categories:

`PrivateServiceProvider` (meaning - private person):

```
class PrivateServiceProvider : Contact
{
    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }
    public ServiceField ServiceField { get; private set; }

    public PrivateServiceProvider(ushort id, string firstName, string lastName,
                                  ServiceField serviceField, Phone phone)
        : base(id, phone)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        ServiceField = serviceField;
    }
}
```

`BusinessServiceProvider`:

```
class BusinessServiceProvider : Contact
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public ServiceField ServiceField { get; private set; }
    public Email Email { get; private set; }

    public BusinessServiceProvider(ushort id, string name,
                                   ServiceField serviceField, Phone phone, Email email)
        : base(id, phone)
    {
        Name = name;
        ServiceField = serviceField;
        Email = email;
    }
}
```

`PrivateGenericContact`:

```
class PrivateGenericContact : Contact
{
    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }

    public PrivateGenericContact(ushort id, string firstName, string lastName, Phone phone)
        : base(id, phone)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

`BusinessGenericContact`:

```
class BusinessGenericContact : Contact
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Email Email { get; private set; }

    public BusinessServiceProvider(ushort id, string name, Phone phone, Email email)
        : base(id, phone)
    {
        Name = name;
        Email = email;
    }
}
```

It works, but how could I improve it<sup>1</sup>?

Also, it drives me CRAZY that the names of the classes are so lengthy. I think it's a smell but I am not sure what to do about it. If some day I decide to create another specification of `Contact`, let's say - for people who lives in the city versus in the country<sup>2</sup>, will I call the class `CountryPrivateServiceProvider`? It's NUTS.

An example of use is when the user creates a contact. So he chooses the type of contact and inserts all of the information into a form (a `View` - I am using MVP). Then the `View` notify the `Presenter` that the user pressed the "Save" and creates an object of the selected type. Then the `Presenter` ask the `Model` to insert the information into the database.

How can I improve my code, both generally and specifically to this naming problem?

---

<sup>1. They are deliberately immutable.</sup>

<sup>2. Apparently, I am not good with examples.</sup>

Comment: Take out the private set; and see if it still works

Comment: @Paparazzi The code works... The setter is private for a reason, that is what makes the objects immutable.

Comment: It is also private if there is no set;    So the code works, the purpose of posting here is to make it better.

Comment: I would say your `ServiceProvider` could rather be using the `GenericContact` as a baseclass. I would rather be unsure if you want such a hard differentation between these classes. Depending on specs that might change these might be classes that will be changed quite often. Also, I don't see how classes that should be editable by a user should be immutable, it seems like a contradition

Comment: `ushort` as a unique identifier type has a bit of a smell. Just stick with `int` unless there's an obvious overriding concern (such as the DB is explicitly absolutely needing a 16-bit unsigned integer).

Answer (score 1):

I find those classes should but just simple POCO classes with `get/set` properties. They could sit either inside a `DTO` or `Model` namespace or could have a `Dto` suffix and simple names like `Person` or `PrivatePerson` or `BusinessPerson`. They are not service providers as you call them.

However, you do want to differentiate between a `PrivateCountry` and a `BusinessCountry`. You could do this by adding the type of operation you need them for, like `PrivateCountryForAddingDto` or `BusinessCountryForUpdatingDto`. With this pattern you will have a few more models but the good thing is that each *command* will have its own independent model that can have its own validation logic. A model for adding does not necessarily have to have the same requirements as a model for updating. Some fields might be optional in one case and mandatory in another case.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents; Lengthy class names are not necessarily a code smell, as long as they are descriptive.

I found the [Ubiquitous Language](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/UbiquitousLanguage.html) in Domain Driven Design an eyeopener in how to structure and name my classes.

The link I provided describes in overview what the Ubiquitous Language is. Google some more to get a good idea of how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea that brings the concept of encapsulation into the mix:

```
class Customer
{
    public ushort Id { get; private set; }

    public Phone Phone { get; private set; }

    public Customer(ushort id, Phone phone)
    {
        Id = id;
        Phone = phone;
    }
}

class Provider : Customer
{
    public Provider(ushort id, Phone phone, ServiceField serviceField): base(id, phone)
    {
    }

    public ServiceField ServiceField { get; private set; }
}

class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }
}

class Business
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Email Email { get; private set; }
}

class PrivateProvider : Provider
{
    public Person Person { get; private set; }

    public PrivateProvider(ushort id, Phone phone, Person person, ServiceField serviceField) : base(id, phone)
    {
        Person = person;
        ServiceField = serviceField;
    }
}


class BusinessProvider : Provider
{
    public Business Business { get; private set; }

    public BusinessProvider(ushort id, Phone phone, Business business, ServiceField serviceField) : base(id, phone)
    {
        Business = business;
        ServiceField = serviceField;
    }
}

class PrivateGeneric : Customer
{
    public Person Person { get; private set; }

    public PrivateGeneric(ushort id, Person person, Phone phone) : base(id, phone)
    {
        Person = person;
    }
}

class BusinessGeneric : Customer
{
    public Business Business { get; private set; }

    public BusinessGeneric(ushort id, Phone phone, Business business) : base(id, phone)
    {
        Business = business;
    }
}
```

And every time you come with a new classification like city vs. country, there are several options including:

1. Make an enum and a new property of the enum type - i.e. `enum Location`
2. Create a new class and encapsulate it - i.e. `class Location` like the example does with Person and Business.
3. Create a new class in the inheritance tree - i.e. `class CityProvider`

Which option to choose depends largely on how the new classification impacts the logic.